# Maven shade plugin does not exclude an artifact

Tags: maven, log4j, maven-shade-plugin

I need to exclude the log4j artifact from the shade plug-in to avoid the log4j vulnerability, however, the exclude tag under artifactSet does not seem to work. Any suggestion to fix this?

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4</version>
~~
<executions>
   <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>*:log4j-core:jar</exclude>
            </excludes>
         </artifactSet>
~~~
```

I keep getting below error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) on project : Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.0

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221326/maven-shade-plugin-failed-to-execute-goal) help? Or maybe just [change the version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704585/maven-shade-plugin-failed-to-execute-goal)?

Comment: The output looks like you don't even use log4j-core...

Comment: thanks TheAmateurCoder and khmarbaise for the comments. I tried changing the versions but getting same error. I want to exclude the log4j-core which this plug-in tries to resolve during build time. It throws this error when I run 'mvn install' command/

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, and finally solved by `maven-shade-plugin` config. In your case, you want to exclude `log4j-core`, your filter config must put outside of `artifactSet` as below.

1. find `log4j-core` class path prefix, for example `org/slf4j/`;
2. put this class path prefix in filter exclude rule, run cmd `mvn package`
3. use `vim your-target.jar` to check exclude success or not, you will find that  `org/slf4j` has gone.
4. for more exclude info, pls see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

   ```
           <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>org/slf4j/**</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
   ```